# Mileage price calculation with script or formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I'm new in this script writing and never been in the deep of google functions so I would like to ask some help.

After a lot of resource I wrote a script to calculate mileage and it does work. :)

Now I would like to calculte the price.

What I thought is display the data (only mileage) by date and then do the calculation under. I just can not figure out a way to display the data by date.

The calculation is a bit difficult. Im open for write script or anything what would solve my problem.

I just share the calculation as maybe someone knows a better way.  I would need to minus 4.26mile from the first entry if that's not home to work.
Home to work - 0 money
Work to first site - -4,26miles the rest of that trip is *0,20p
the rest of the miles for the day is *0,40p

I link a copy of the spreadsheet feel free to make any changes.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bGLeSoeEunvK1mMBxnldZ67nJX0eXctdhFTbOEj_K3g/edit?usp=sharing

I would really really appricate some help. I done so much resource reading and watch video but I still can't figure a way.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: I think I fixed it.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share what is your actual vs intended output to clarify what you want to achieve? Is this ```=sum(C2-4.6)*0.2+(C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8)*0.4``` the operation you want to achieve across all the columns ```A-G``` in the ```Price``` sheet? Or is your problem that you dont know how to import the data by date from sheet ```Calculation``` to sheet ```Price```?

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to import the data based on the date to price from calculation tab. I'm not even sure if the function I wrote the most efficient way to do the sum. I would like to have the mileage from calculation H column to Price under the date. As the calculation is a bit difficult I though to add the data and do the calculation underneath,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to import only the miles that correspond with each matching date you can use the function [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) which will take a column (in your case `H`) and return a range of values of this column if a range condition is met (in your case if the date values of `B` correspond with the date you are searching for). This is all wrapped in an [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) function so that filter does not throw and error when it does not find any match and instead it just displays a blank cell.

Add this in `C2` and then drag horizontally to get the rest of your dates:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(Calculation!$H$2:$H$43,Calculation!$B$2:$B$43=C1))
```

Comment: Thank very much for your help. I will try it as soon as Im around a computer.